# Determine a region of the $xy$-plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine a region of the $xy$-plane for which the differential equation 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+2) e^{(y/{x+2})} $$ would have a unique solution through a point $(x_0, y_0)$ in the region.

Comment: Did you make a mistake with the $(x+2)$ both at the numerator and denominator?

Comment: @user58315, Is the edited version correct?

Comment: @jun Look at the edits, Chokladkakan copied the OP correctly.

Comment: Ah okay, its OP's error as he admitted.

Comment: When you receive an answer that is helpful, we encourage you to upvote it, and for each question asked, you can accept *one* answer. To accept an answer, just click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. You get 2 reputation points for each answer accepted, and you can say "thank you", as well, by upvoting all helpful answers and accepting one.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), if $y'=f(x,y)$ and we know that both of $f(x,y),~~f_y$ are continuous on a rectangular area $R$ including the points$ (x_0,y_0)$; then there is an interval $I$ centered at that point and the unique function $y$ defined on $I$ satisfying the intial-value problem. Now have a look at the $f(x,y)$ and $f_y$ for your OE.

Comment: Nice link and use of the theorem! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Yes. I t is really a good Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $t=x+2\implies dx=dt$ which gives, $$\frac{dy}{dt}=te^{y/t}$$

Now, substitute, $y=tz\implies \frac{dy}{dt}=z+t\frac{dz}{dt}$ which gives $$z+t\frac{dz}{dt}=te^z$$ and assuming $t\neq 0$ rearrangement gives $$\frac{dz}{dt}+\frac{1}{t}z=e^z$$

This is standard linear differential equation in $z$(can be solved using standard procedures) which has a unique solution given it passes through $(x_0,y_0)$. Therefore, for $t\neq 0\iff x\neq -2$ is the region where it has unique solution.

Comment: Sorry I made an error in the question, it is now revised

Comment: i edited my answer. Have a look